# 'kCLErrorDomain error 2' on iOS simulator

Tags: swift, core-location

I'm making a app and finally reach the end.

my app present some location with MapKit with using geocodeAddressString on CLGeocoder.

```
    func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            if let error = error {
                let _ = print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
                return
            }
            completion(location)
        }
    }
```

It works fine on my test devices iPhone 13 mini (iOS 16), iPad mini (iOS 16), iPhone 7 (iOS 15).

Actually any other case rely on simulator, because i can't hold all devices.

Like iPad 12.9 (6th gen), iPad 12.9 (2nd gen), iPhone 14 pro has unique interface, i need to test about it.
But it doesn't work and return error 'kCLErrorDomain error 2'

this is an error on CoreLocation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clerror/code

and it mean network error.

So, I need to know this error cause on simulator or really i find to solve this.
please help.

Some result of search, they says 'it use actual server and request recommend 1 per minute.'

It makes fewer than 10 requests, but they are very one-offs at initialization time.

So I don't think request throttling is the problem.

Comment: Is simulating location on?

Comment: thanks to your comment. but simulator's location set to work.
And additional information here, 'maps' on simulator was not working.
i ignore it and my app requested to review now.